# Как создать множественный input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание:
Данные в этой задаче устроены так: число в первой строчке показывает сколько еще строчек с числами нужно прочитать. Например:

```
5
4
-10
9
2
3
```

В примере выше сначала обозначено количество чисел, потом сами числа. Напишите строчку кода, которая прочитает все числа и напечатает их сумму.

Да, в этой задаче, в отличие от предыдущих, вам нужно самим вызывать функцию print.

**Нужно записать все в одну строку**

Код:

```
print(sum(int(i)) - i[0] for i in str(input()))
```

Comment: а, значения подаются не в строку...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что на счёт этого? Для поставленной задачи очень удобно создать массив с помощью генератора и далее передать его в `sum`.

```
print(sum([int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как создать множественный input?

Просто вызывайте `input` столько раз, сколько необходимо:

- В первый раз, чтобы получить количество
- Во-второй раз, в цикле

Пример:

```
# Первая строка -- количество чисел
n = int(input())

# Все оставшиеся числа n-раз
items = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
```

В одну строку:

```
items = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

---

**PS.**

А чтобы суммировать, то `sum(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))`

Comment: да но требуется решить в одну строку

Comment: @finally, не заметил, спс )

Answer (score 1):

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in input().split()[1:]))
```

Comment: выводится как объект генератор, а  нужно число

Comment: @finally, вводится несколькими строками, а `input()` всегда считывает только по одной строке. Ваш код считает только первую строку - ту которая с количеством строк данных.

Comment: @insolor до правки пример ввода был в одну строку